# Java SocketChannel cannot send data to ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java, socketchannel

I am trying to write a simple client/server in Java using NIO and Selectors. The server is very easy and it's the most typical implementation that you can find everywhere. Here's the code of the server (look at the `start()` method):

```
public final class MyServer {

    private int port;

    private String address;

    public MyServer(String address, int port) {
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {

        try {

            Selector selector = Selector.open();    

            ServerSocketChannel socket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);

            socket.bind(addr);
            socket.configureBlocking(false);

            boolean isAlive = true;
            SelectionKey selectKy = socket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT, null);

            while (isAlive) {

                selector.select();

                Set<SelectionKey> keysList = selector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = keysList.iterator();

                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey theKey = keys.next();

                    if (theKey.isAcceptable()) {

                        SocketChannel clientSocket = socket.accept();
                        clientSocket.configureBlocking(false);
                        clientSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

                    }

                    if (theKey.isReadable()) {

                        SocketChannel clientSocket = (SocketChannel) theKey.channel();
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(9000);
                        clientSocket.read(buffer);

                        String result = new String(buffer.array()).trim();
                        System.out.println(" > SERVER: Request from " + clientSocket.getLocalAddress() + " [ toValidate = " + result + " ], sending tokens...");

                        //Now I send to the client a list
                        buffer.flip();

                        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                            buffer.put((byte) getRandom(1, 10));

                        clientSocket.write(buffer);
                        buffer.clear();

                        System.out.println(" > SERVER: Response successfully sent");
                    }

                    keys.remove();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[ SERVER ALERT: " + e.getMessage() + " ]");
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see, the code is pretty basic. Inside the `if (theKey.isReadable())` I try to read a small string from the client, I print it to the console, then I flip the buffer and I send some data back to the client.

---

Here we have the client that sadly has a problem I cannot find:

```
public void something() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(9000);

        //Note that mRequests is a List of strings
        try (SocketChannel client = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(authIPAddr, authPort));) {
            //For each transaction in mRequests, get the tokens from the server and verify them
            for (String s : mRequests) {

                //Write the string to the buffer and send the string
                buffer.put(s.getBytes());
                client.write(buffer);

                buffer.rewind();

                //Get response from the server
                client.read(buffer);
                buffer.clear();      

                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is exactly here:

```
buffer.put(s.getBytes());
client.write(buffer);

buffer.rewind();
```

I can say that the problem is there because the server should print

> SERVER: Request from /127.0.0.1:2323 [ toValidate = {some_value} ], sending
>   tokens...

but instead it prints

> SERVER: Request from /127.0.0.1:2323 [ toValidate =  ], sending
>   tokens...

and from this I guess that data arent sent to the server. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you change the line where you are reading to this: `int read = clientSocket.read(buffer);` and check how many bytes you have read? Also change where you are converting the buffer to a `String` to `buffer.asCharBuffer().toString()`

Comment: @jbx I have solved the issue, it seems! I have removed the try-with-resources and I have called client.close() outside the for loop (in the client). I do not know why but it works...